# Attach bootstrap dropdown to different element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to choose which element my bootstrap dropdown aligns with when it is opened. Is this possible? I'm open to doing it programmatically with AngularJS or JavaScript.

Currently I have a textbox with a button dropdown appended to it. Similar to this:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Some Action</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like the dropdown to align so it drops down from the text box instead of the button. I can't just move it over *n* pixels because the input box's width is relative to the screen size.

Comment: Sorry this is a bit of a vague answer, but I had this same issue some time ago. If I recall correctly, I just made the button (dropdown-toggle) invisible, and triggered a jQuery click from another button elsewhere on the page. It's been some time since I did it, but hopefully that gives you something to start with.

Comment: @trnelson, this is a clever idea that may help me out in the future, but dfsq's answer did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Ah great! Looking back, I actually misread your question. :) I was thinking you needed to trigger a dropdown from a button elsewhere on the page. My mistake. Glad you got your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can fix it by applying one more class to `.input-group-btn` div:

```
<div class="input-group-btn input-group-btn-static">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="drop">
        <li><a href="#">Some Action</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-group-btn-static {
    position: static;
}
```

The idea is to make dropdown position relatively to `<div class="input-group"></div>` instead of `div.input-group-btn`.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Dfq41N5T4WwUMAJL1NYb?p=preview

Comment: Wow, just that easy. Thanks.